# Functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ commuting with orthogonal transformations

Tags: transformation, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, nonlinear-analysis

I am interested in finding the functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $f \circ U = U \circ f$ for all orthogonal transformations $U:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that $f$ need not be linear. Any ideas on the conditions on $f$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See my answer + comments at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591815/let-v-be-spherically-symmetric-and-w-i-i-d-gaussian-then-evvw-t-g-t/2592127#2592127

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533891/what-are-some-interesting-functions-that-are-equivariant-under-rotations-in-so3/2534273#2534273